# Non-resonant source in a conducting cavity, what happens?

Tags: electromagnetism, frequency, conductors, resonance

First of all I'm aware of [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/171185/) but my question is a little different.

Say we have a perfectly conducting cavity with supported frequencies $\omega_n$ and a harmonically varying source within oscillating at a frequency $\omega$ different from all $\omega_n$. There's no way for the wave to escape and yet the cavity does not support standing waves at this frequency so what happens?

Comment: You already got a good answer, but I just wanted to say this is no more puzzling than pushing a mass on a spring back and forth at a frequency not equal to its resonant frequency. Any subtlety of the cavity case is also present in this trivial case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view a cavity as many independent $LC$ circuits, each circuit corresponding to a specific mode with resonant frequency $\omega_n$. You can now excite the cavity by introducing variable charge and density with harmonic time dependence at a non resonant frequency $\omega$. This amounts to exciting each LC circuit at the frequency $\omega$ at various amounts (the amounts depends on how the source decompose in the mode's basis). Thus, each mode has a harmonic time dependence at frequency $\omega$ plus a free oscillation at the resonant frequency $\omega_n$ in order to match the initial condition. In the real spatial domain, the fields at a specific position will be superposition of signals at all the frequencies $\omega_n$ due to the initial condition and a signal at frequency $\omega$.

Things change when $\omega$ matches a resonant frequency. Indeed, this will correspond to a pole of the response function. You expect it to be second order, so you'll have an oscillation due to the initial condition and another oscillation at the same resonant frequency, this time modulated by a linearly increasing amplitude.

Take for example a cubic box of side length $1$. I'll set $\mu_0=\epsilon_0=1$. Your modes are of the form (method of images):
$$
\begin{align}
E &= \begin{pmatrix}
\hat E_x \cos(k_xx)\sin(k_yy)\sin(k_zz) \\
\hat E_y \sin(k_xx)\cos(k_yy)\sin(k_zz) \\
\hat E_z \sin(k_xx)\sin(k_yy)\cos(k_zz)
\end{pmatrix} &
B &= \begin{pmatrix}
\hat B_x \sin(k_xx)\cos(k_yy)\cos(k_zz) \\
\hat B_y \cos(k_xx)\sin(k_yy)\cos(k_zz) \\
\hat B_z \cos(k_xx)\cos(k_yy)\sin(k_zz)
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
$$
with $k = \pi n$ with $n\in\mathbb N^3-\{(0,0,0)\}$. The sources are more conveniently expressed in the modes:
$$
\begin{align}
\rho &= \hat \rho \sin(k_xx)\sin(k_yy)\sin(k_zz) &
j &= \begin{pmatrix}
\hat j_x \cos(k_xx)\sin(k_yy)\sin(k_zz) \\
\hat j_y \sin(k_xx)\cos(k_yy)\sin(k_zz) \\
\hat j_z \sin(k_xx)\sin(k_yy)\cos(k_zz)
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
$$
The Maxwell's equations become, assuming an $e^{i\omega t}$ time dependence:
$$
\begin{align}
-k\cdot \hat E &= \hat \rho & k\cdot \hat B &= 0 \\
k\times \hat E &= -i\omega \hat B & -k\times \hat B &= \hat j + i\omega \hat E
\end{align}
$$
You can solve these equations for any source provided they satisfy the continuity equation:
$$
i\omega\hat \rho -k\cdot \hat j = 0
$$
You should get:
$$
\begin{align}
E &= -i\frac{\omega}{k^2-\omega^2}\left(\hat j+i\frac{k}{\omega}\hat\rho\right) & B &= \frac{k}{k^2-\omega^2}\times\left(\hat j+i\frac{k}{\omega}\hat\rho\right) 
\end{align}
$$
You can identify the resonant frequency of the mode $k$ to be $\omega_k = |k|$. As long as you are off resonance for all modes, you will get a finite amplitude for all modes. Note that due to the pole, you get a Dirac delta contribution at the singularity. In the temporal domain, this means that you need add resonant solutions to match the initial condition. Your modes are just solutions of the eigenvalue equation without the sources. You have two transverse polarisations per wavenumber as in the infinite volume case with $E,B$ related by:
$$
\begin{align}
k\times \hat E &= i\omega \hat B
\end{align}
$$

Probably the simplest example of a source would be an oscillating dipole. If it is an electric dipole, then the sources are given by:
$$
\begin{align}
\rho(r) &= -\nabla\cdot p\delta(r-r') & j(x) &= \dot p\delta(r-r') \\
\hat\rho(r) &= k\cdot \hat p & j(x) &= i\omega \hat p 
\end{align}\\
\hat p = \begin{pmatrix}
p_x \cos(k_xx’)\sin(k_yy’)\sin(k_zz’) \\
p_y \sin(k_xx’)\cos(k_yy’)\sin(k_zz’) \\
p_z \sin(k_xx’)\sin(k_yy’)\cos(k_zz’)
\end{pmatrix} 
$$
If it is a magnetic dipole, then the sources are given by:
$$
\begin{align}
\rho(r) &= 0 & j(r) &= \nabla\times m \delta(r-r')\\
\hat\rho &= 0 & \hat j &= -k\times \hat m
\end{align}\\
\hat m = \begin{pmatrix}
m_x \sin(k_xx’)\cos(k_yy’)\cos(k_zz’) \\
m_y \cos(k_xx’)\sin(k_yy’)\cos(k_zz’) \\
m_z \cos(k_xx’)\cos(k_yy’)\sin(k_zz’)
\end{pmatrix}
$$

**Answer to comment**

The analogy with the LC circuit still applies. You are just multiplying the harmonic forcing by a rectangular function. You have many options for calculating the response.

A first method would be to calculate the impulse response. I already gave you the transfer function in frequency space, so doing the Fourier transform gives you the impulse response. Now you just need to convolve it with your new forcing.

You could also stay in frequency space. Multiplying by a rectangular function in time space is equivalent to convolving by a sinus cardinal in frequency space. Your forcing is therefore not a Dirac delta but is rather spread out to be a sinus cardinal. By multiplying it with the transfer function, you get the response.

Finally, you can just solve it piecewise which is what you had in mind. Before and after the window, you just have a free oscillation of the modes. In the window, you need to add the inhomogeneous solution oscillating at frequency $\omega$. The choice of the homogeneous solution is determined by an initial value and by matching so that the solution is always continuously differentiable.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, that was great. Here's a followup question. Let's say we have a source at a non-resonant frequency $\omega$ which is only turned on for some finite period of time $T$, what happens to the waves inside the cavity afterwards? Since we're back to the free solution only $\omega_n$ are allowed so I must conclude that the original component at $\omega$ disappears. (I understand that oscillations over a finite period of time are not technically pure fourier modes, but for sufficiently large $T$ I think this is still a relevant question)

Answer (score 0):

If the cavity is lossless then the same thing would happen as would with an RF source driving an ideal LC circuit: to the source it represents a reactive load and gets reflected completely. If it drives it at a resonant or anti-resonant frequency then that is either a short circuit or an open circuit. In general, even at low powers, any reactive load  is rarely tolerated well by the usual RF/microwave/optical sources, and the most likely thing to happen is a flash and then nothing at best, and at worst, you blow up the lab...

Comment: What does this mean in terms of the field? Does the amplitude of the standing wave just continually increase in the cavity?

Comment: Say it is a resonant short circuit loading a voltage source, the standing wave increases its amplitude until the source blows up; or the source just does not like any reflected wave and then blows up. Usually, RF sources are designed always to have a specific "matched" load in mind to prevent such unfortunate event. When such load cannot be guaranteed there may be a ferrite isolator placed between the source and the load to absorb the reflected wave but that method can be costly both in money and transmission loss.

Comment: When thinking of a cavity the easiest intuition is to think of it as having an ideal transformer at its drive port whose primary is connected to a voltage or current source and for each mode in the cavity there is a secondary  "coil" such that to each secondary there is attached an infinite number of series connected parallel resonators or an infinite number of parallel connected series resonators; but usually, the operation can be approximated well by including one such resonator for each mode. Also, modes whose resonant frequencies are far from the operating frequency can also be neglected.